# How do I retrofit a junction box in an insulated wall?

Tags: electrical, insulation, vapor-barrier, retrofit

Typical cold climate construction: Drywall, 6mil vapour barrier, fiberglass batt insulation. How do I retrofit a junction box and maintain the vapour seal? To be clear, by 'retrofit', I mean the drywall is up and I'd like to install this without having to repair any drywall.

Typically for new construction, you'd use an insulated and sealed box:

[image]

The vapour barrier is sealed against the gasket when drywall goes up.

Obviously, there's no way to get this box into a wall without removing a large chunk of drywall.

Does a product exist for this? How do you get a box into the wall and maintain the seal with the vapour barrier, without any access to the inside of the wall beyond the hole the box will fill up?

*(actually fishing the wire to this box is beyond the scope of this question)*

---

**EDIT:**

This worked brilliantly.

[image]

I cut a square hole out of the existing vapour barrier, then pushed the vapour box in behind it and spread it out. I then used tuck tape to attach from the back of the existing vapour barrier to the vapour box (using several small overlapping pieces), and had enough room to fit in a regular old work box.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking about keeping the seal to stop air infiltration into the living space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll have to get one of these vapor barrier boxes, and fit it before installing your electrical box.

[image]

Seal up where the cable penetrates, then install your electrical box.

The other options would be to cut a larger hole and patch drywall, or seal it up from the back side (but that would require access to the other side of the wall/ceiling).

Comment: Ah, that is brilliant, I totally forgot those existed. After that I can just use a regular old-work box (or even low-voltage box, if applicable) and it should be fine.

Comment: where do you buy these?

Comment: I just got a couple at a big orange box store last night, on the shelf next to the junction boxes. True story: the girl at checkout picked it up and said "woah, there's a barcode on this? I was about to throw it out, thought it was a piece of packaging or something"

Comment: @Tester101 What are the ramifications of installing the electrical box in an outside wall and *not* patching the vapor barrier or using a vapor barrier box?  Does it just reduce the efficiency of the insulation or is it a code/safety issue?